# Executing multiple .bat or .exe files

Tags: phpdesktop

I am using *PHP Desktop* to turn my web app into "desktop app". Is it possible and if it is how can I execute multiple .bat or .exe files after executing the main .exe file? 
Also is it possible to execute .bat or .exe file with button using JavaScript?

Comment: Question is unclear to me... Could you please give more information about your application and its execution context?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use PHP functions like system() to execute any command.

There is also a "nircmd" tool that has many options including options to execute programs asynchronously. See:

https://github.com/cztomczak/phpdesktop/wiki/Knowledge-Base#how-do-i-call-external-programs-or-commands-asynchronously-in-background-without-waiting-for-them-to-end

If you want to execute program with js then just make an AJAX call to a PHP script.